# ActionScript 3 Examples (Code Only)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there anywhere a GOOD tutorial page where I can learn ActionScript 3 ? Or can you help me out ?

I don't use a ***GRAPHICAL DESIGNER*** and I don't want to. **All I need is code.**

For example: things I need to learn quick:

1. Buttons and TextFields (basic form stuff)
2. Drawing canvas (like the html5 canvas)

Using FlashDevelop + Flash SDK, no plugins, no nothing. I just got it to work (compile, build and start a blank piece of nothing) and now I need to see what I can do with the ActionScript code.

---

**Solved:** Thanks to Dannyw the 2 items above could be solved directly (with minor additions)!

Julian's answer is very helpful too. Since I also wanted to browse through all standard classes in Flash:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html

Comment: You might want to rethink your attitude. What you're saying is: "I want to learn how to build a house, and I don't know anything yet. But I don't want to use a hammer, so please only show me stuff I can do with a screwdriver."

Comment: Your assumption that using an IDE prevents you from writing code is what's wrong. It's a toolbox; no more, no less. No magic involved.

Comment: Seems like FlashDevelop is an IDE as well... In any case, I suggest just searching google for those two specific things you mentioned. Also once you get an idea of what you want to make, specific examples in the adobe actionscript 3 api reference site can help.

Comment: @weltraumpirat I must excuse myself I was confused about the keyword "IDE" I though it meant the designer thing. You also should have noticed if I say "don't use IDE", "want code" and "use FlashDevelop" that there is something wrong with my IDE definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For buttons:

http://www.how-to-code.com/as3-actionscript3/as3-buttons/as3-button.html

For Textfields:

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3text/

For Drawing:

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3drawvectors/

I learnt actionscript the same way you intend to, just by reading tutorials on the internet and picking bits up as I went along. I eventually bought myself a big old actionscript bible too (Essential Actionscript 3.0 by Colin Moock), but can safely say that the internet was my most valuable resource!

Have fun with the tutorials :)

Answer (score 3):

I have some tips for you to become a great flashdeveloper:

- Drop everything you know, start fresh. You have strange assumptions of how the workflow should be. If you want to become professional, you should be open for other workflows.
- If your coming from actionscript 2, Dont think as2 is like as3, so don't try to do the AS2 thing with AS3. Again, drop everything you know.
- Read & Learn the Adobe LiveDocs
- Learn how the display list works.
- Learn AS3 coding standards, learn to write clean readable code, later try to learn design patterns.
- Learn how to use common actionscript libraries, TweenLite, Gaia framework, RobotLegs, Temple Library, Pure MVC, Away3D, as3corelib etc.
- Dont try to reinvent the wheel, dont create your own framework, because you think there is none like yours, most starters step into that trap.
- Code never inside the Flash IDE actionspanel, there are really nice actionscript editors like FlashDevelop, FDT, FlashBuilder, IntelliJ. But dont lose yourself in code, there is a lot visual stuff that can faster be build using the Flash IDE, so find a nice workflow, instead of limiting yourself.
- if you like video tutorials; videos on gotoAndLearn.com, most have common practices.
- If you like to learn from opensource projects: find as3 projects on github.com or wonderfl, check out how they did it.
- if you like to read blogs: feeds.adobe.com is full of nice relavant blogs. Learn from the best.

Last but not least: there is no ultimate guide to become a flashdevelop-code-only-flash-developer. Like sport, you have to train and just experiment right away. So be open, use google alot, try to challenge yourself with excercises and fun experiments.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html

BTW, You should almostly declare this website as holy when programming in AS3.

Answer (score 0):

Using adobe flash or macromedia is recommended, follow these tutorials I learnt everything about flash from this website.

http://www.lynda.com/Flash-CS5-tutorials/flash-professional-cs5-essential-training/59964-2.html